# 500 error for all pages and post after move localhost to server

Tags: errors, 500-internal-error

today i move to the folder local to server after that i got 500 error for pages and post

but in home page everything showing fine but other linkes are not working

**what i did?**

1. add apache2 conf and point domains
2. edited database (checg http://localhost/triber to realdomian)

**what happen after that?**

only home is is working fine images are other post are showing but other links are not working

**error messages**

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

same other question abut my issues

[1.Can't access wp-admin Internal Server Error 500](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319495/cant-access-wp-admin-internal-server-error-500)

[2.500 Internal Server Error after Register dialog, but with successful registration](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88477/500-internal-server-error-after-register-dialog-but-with-successful-registratio)

[3.500 Internal server error after changing php version](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241728/500-internal-server-error-after-changing-php-version)

[4.500 error after WordPress homepage URL changed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212032/500-error-after-wordpress-homepage-url-changed/239985#239985)

[5.Wordpress HTTP 500 Error](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247503/wordpress-http-500-error)

[6.500 Internal Server Error after attempting to switch from subdirectory to addon domain](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/294647/500-internal-server-error-after-attempting-to-switch-from-subdirectory-to-addon?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change database name, username and password in the config.php file

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'DB_NAME');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'DB_USERNAME');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_PASSWORD');
```

then upload the database and run the following queries, this will change all the local links to your live url

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

After this wp-admin should work, then login and go to settings>permalink and hit save which will reset the redirects.

[image]